# Recursive schema with avro (SchemaBuilder)

Tags: java, avro, recursive-datastructures

Is it possible to make an avro schema which is recursive, like

```
Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
    .record("RecursiveItem")
    .namespace("com.example")
    .fields()
    .name("subItem")
    .type("RecursiveItem")
    .withDefault(null) // not sure about that too...
    .endRecord();
```

I get a StackOverflowError when using it like that:

```
static class RecursiveItem {
  RecursiveItem subItem;
}

RecursiveItem item1 = new RecursiveItem();
RecursiveItem item2 = new RecursiveItem();
item1.subItem = item2;

final DatumWriter<RecursiveItem> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);

// note: I actually want a binary output, but I started with some json code I found
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, stream);
writer.write(rec1, encoder);
String json = stream.toString();
```

Note: I also get StackOverflowError if I make the schema using:

```
Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(RecursiveItem.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I found a solution to write, but cannot read it bask :-\

I am not sure to really understand, but I manage to make it works with:

1. `ReflectDatumWriter` should be used instead of `SpecificDatumWriter`
2. I still had issue with schema not found due to automated lookup of schema upon encoding. It looks for a schema with a namespace+name derived automatically. And in my case where the class is a static subclass, the following should be used:

   ```
   String cls = RecursiveItem.class.getSimpleName();
   String pck = RecursiveItem.class.getPackage().getName();
   if (RecursiveItem.class.getEnclosingClass() != null) // nested class
     pck = RecursiveItem.class.getEnclosingClass().getName() + "$";
   ```
3. To manage the null, the following schema should be used

   ```
   Schema schema0 = SchemaBuilder
     .record(cls)
     .namespace(pck)
     .fields()
     .name("subItem")
     .type().unionOf().nullType().and().type("RecursiveItem").endUnion()
     .nullDefault()
     .endRecord();
   ```